# Acumatica Generic Inquiry Adding to Inquiries Menu (Automation Steps)

Tags: customization, acumatica

Adding GIs to the report menu is easy enough but in [this Technical Tuesday post](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/technical-tuesday-adding-items-to-the-inquiries-and-reports-menus-part2/) Doug describes some additional steps that need to be followed with customization in order to add a GI to the INQUIRIES menu:
[image]

Anybody have any luck following his steps? I kept getting lots of validation errors with the code he shared and would appreciate a better explanation.

After the customization step, we just have to add it to the Automation Step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below customization code until we fix the issues with the Technical Tuesday post.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.PO;

namespace PXDemoPkg
{
    public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
    {

        public PXAction<POOrder> inquiry;

        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inquiries", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        protected virtual IEnumerable Inquiry(PXAdapter adapter,
            [PXInt] [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                               new string[] { "Vendor Details", "Activities", "PO Prepayments" })] int? inquiryID)
        {
            if (inquiryID == 3)
            {
                POOrder order = Base.Document.Current;

                string giURL = PXGenericInqGrph.INQUIRY_URL;
                string gIName = "POprepayments";
                string sParameter1Name = "POnumber";
                string sParameter1Value = order.OrderNbr;

                string url = String.Format("{0}?Name={1}&{2}={3}", giURL, gIName, sParameter1Name, sParameter1Value);

                throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, true, "POprepayments-GI");
            }
            else
                return Base.inquiry.Press(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Way better method not having to specify the URL :)

Comment: @Ahmed, you're most welcome. And Tech Tuesday post is corrected as well.